# pam_limits(cron:session): unknown limit item 'nofiles'

Tags: debian-squeeze, logging

On my debian-squeeze server I get thousands of messages in the logcheck email under

```
Security Events for sudo
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
Aug 31 20:17:44 eclabs sudo: pam_limits(sudo:session): unknown limit item 'nofiles'
Aug 31 20:17:44 eclabs sudo: pam_limits(sudo:session): unknown limit item 'nofiles'

System Events
=-=-=-=-=-=-=
Aug 31 18:45:01 eclabs CRON[31531]: pam_limits(cron:session): unknown limit item 'nofiles'
Aug 31 18:45:01 eclabs CRON[31531]: pam_limits(cron:session): unknown limit item 'nofiles'
Aug 31 18:45:01 eclabs CRON[31530]: pam_limits(cron:session): unknown limit item 'nofiles'
...
```

How can I understand these messages and what should I do? How do I find out in which log these lines appear?

Comment: can you also post `limit.conf` what you have configured

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `/etc/security/limits.conf` and look if you have an entry with attribute "nofiles" which should read "nofile" (without 's').

Comment: That was it! I got it here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85457/how-to-circumvent-too-many-open-files-in-debian there i made that typo with "nofiles".